# Why is Outlooks ignoring my div width?

Tags: html, css

My heights seems to be fine but my widths are just stretching to fit the width of the email client.

CSS:

```
.info {
    width:560px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#003777;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="info">
  <p>For more information, please contact your account manager</p>
</div>
```

I've also tried using Inline-CSS as is know email clients sometimes don't like CSS very much but it still gets ignored.

Comment: Don't use `div` in html emails, only `table`.. email clients all strip some styling and interpret elements differently.. `table` seems to be the most cross-client way to structure html emails, it's also recommended to not use `p` tags anymore, instead use `span`

Comment: Outlook 2007 and later use Microsoft Word's browser engine.

Comment: Haha, typical that I've recently gone from being a newbie coder and using tables for designing, to divs, and now I meant to use tables! -_- thank you for your input @DannyHearnah. would it be possible to drop my divs into a table to contain the width as my email is all made and I don't fancy making it all again

Comment: A quick test shows that it ignores the width and height and padding, but not the font size or colors. Oh well, email clients eh.

Comment: @Adsy i would drop `div` all together.. go back to the basics :-) if you're making this newsletter from a template (fireworks) then use their export tool.. it exports in tables by default and then you're half way there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use table layout for Outlook, cause it will not understand div's

Answer (score 0):

Email Clients dont work well with DIVs, try to build it in TABLEs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Email clients are not very modern when it comes to handling HTML. You would have to use tables to build  your structure!